# Uniqueness for classical solution of PDE

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, hyperbolic-equations

I have the following conservation law in my hand:

> $\partial_{t} u + \partial_{x}f(u) = -u$, with the associated initial
>   data $u(x,0) = u_{0}(x)$ - where $u_{0} \in C^{1}$.
>
> **I have to show classical solution ($u \in C^{1}$) of the equation is
>   unique**.

***My thoughts***

For me the obvious approach was to show the $L^{1}$-contraction, i.e. assuming  $\exists$ two $C^{1}$-functions $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ which solve the above conservation law with initial data $u_{0,1}(x)$ and $u_{0,2}(x)$ to show

$||u_{1}(\cdot,t) - u_{2}(\cdot,t)||_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})} \leq ||u_{0,1}(\cdot) - u_{0,2}(\cdot)||_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}$.

With this aim in mind I subtracted two conservation laws given by $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ and multiply the resulting equation by a smooth function $\eta'(w)$ where $w = u_{1} - u_{2}$ and $\eta$ is a smooth approximation of modulus.

Can someone show me how to estimate the terms $\eta'(w) \partial_{x}(f(u_{1}) - f(u_{2}))$ and $\eta'(w)w$ ??

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: The two solutions will agree on the same initial condition, ie $u_{0,1}=u_{0,2}$. And does uniqueness not follow from Kruzkov's uniqueness result ?

Comment: I agree!! and then I will have uniqueness!!...But how?? That is the question !! How to get rid of two other terms to obtain the inequality??

@Hirak, ... For a classical solution, in my opinion it will be sloppy to use doubling of variable!! I think it can be achieved without invoking Kruzkov!!

Comment: This is a balance rather than a conservation law, so maybe look into the literature therein.